# How to retrieve blob data from MySql table and return it as Json format?

Tags: c#, mysql, json

I have a table with three columns

```
  MyDate : DateiIme
  MyBlob: blob
  Id: String
```

I want to return MyDate and MyBlob as Json. There can be multiple records in the table.

```
      public class MyData
      {
          public  string? MyDate { get; set; };
          public  string? MyBlob { get; set; };
      }

  public async Task<string> GetQueryResult(string Id)
    {
        MyData data = new MyData();
        List<MyData> MyList = new List<MyData>();
        string sqlSelect = string.Format("Select MyDate, MyBlob from MyTablee WHERE Id = '{0}'", Id);
      
        try
        {

            MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand();
            MySqlConnection connetcion = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            sqlcmd.Connection = connetcion;
            sqlcmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlSelect;
            connetcion.Open();

            using (connetcion)
            {
                int count = 0;
                using (MySqlDataReader reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        data.MyDate = reader.GetString(0);
                        data.MyBlob = reader.GetString(1);
                        MyList.Add(data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(results);

        return json;
    }
```

The output in the Postman is:

```
   "{\"MyDate\":\"1/30/2023 9:16:40 PM\",\"MyBlob\":\"@MyBlob\"}"
```

I am not sure the blob data to JSON conversion is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's probable that your table doesn't contain any BLOB data, but instead contains the literal string `@MyBlob` in that column.

The cause of this would be using a SQL statement like `INSERT INTO MyTablee(MyDate, MyBlob) VALUES(NOW, '@MyBlob');`, which inserts the literal text `@MyBlob`.

Make sure your insert code is constructed as follows:

```cs
using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTablee(MyDate, MyBlob) VALUES(NOW(), @blob);";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blob", yourBlobDataHere);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In particular, there are no quotes around the parameter name in the `INSERT` statement, and command parameters are being used to send values, instead of string concatenation.